# RegEx match for digit in parenthesis (literature reference)

Tags: python, regex

I have the following german text with some literature references:

> ... Im Rahmen der psychologischen  Anwendungsfächer hat sie in den
>   letzten Jahren einen rasanten Zuwachs zu verzeichnen, sowohl
>   hinsichtlich ihrer Forschungsindikatoren *(Publikationen,
>   Drittmitteleinwerbungen, Berufungen auf Professuren)* als auch ihrer
>   praktischen Bedeutung, insbesondere im Diskurs  der Empirischen
>   Bildungsforschung und – nicht zuletzt – der Anzahl ihrer  Lehrbücher
>   und Nachschlagewerke **(Hasselhorn & Gold, 2017; Klauer  & Leutner,
>   2012; Renkl, 2008; Rost, Sparfeldt & Buch, 2018; Seidel &  Krapp,
>   2014; Schnotz, 2011; Wild & Möller, 2015 etc.)**. Warum und mit 
>   welchem Ziel also, so kann man berechtigt fragen, noch ein Lehrbuch 
>   der Pädagogischen Psychologie? Mit der Umstellung der
>   Psychologieausbildung an den deutschen Universitäten vom Diplom- auf
>   ein Bachelor-Master-System *(BSc/MSc)*  ist auch für die Pädagogische
>   Psychologie eine neue Situation entstanden. Das Rahmenmodell zur
>   Ausgestaltung des BSc/MSc-Angebots  der Deutschen Gesellschaft für
>   Psychologie **(DGPs, 20051)** fasst die  Pädagogische Psychologie
>   unter die „etablierten Anwendungsfächer  der Psychologie“ und sieht
>   deren Einführung im Studienmodell schon  für das 3. und 4.
>   Fachsemester im Bachelor-Studiengang vor...  Folgt  man der
>   Argumentation von Vertretern behavioristischer Lehrzieldefinitionen,
>   dann besteht ein Lehrziel in der Bewältigung einer Menge  von
>   Aufgaben, die ihrerseits wiederum einen Gegenstandsbereich vollständig
>   oder repräsentativ abbilden **(Klauer, 1987)**.

The goal is to match the bold substrings while omitting the italic ones. The rule should be something like "match anything in parentheses that has at least a digit in it".

I tried it with rules like `\(.*?\d+.*?\)` but that matches over the first two parentheses blocks, from `(Publikationen` to `etc.)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 2 negated character classes matching any char except a digit or parenthesis before the digit, and match any char except parenthesis after the digit.

```
\([^()\d]*\d[^()]*\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`

  - `[^()\d]*` Match 0+ times any char except `(`, `)` or a digit
  - `\d` Match a digit
  - `[^()]*` Match 0+ times any char except `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sbiWJQ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jvGf6D)

Comment: Bird #1 will be proud!

Answer (score 3):

This should work for your example text you gave us.  Make sure you don't match a `)`.

```
\([^)]*?\d+.*?\)
```